# Python, a smarter way of string to integer conversion

Tags: python, string, integer, type-conversion

I have written this code to convert string in such format "0(532) 222 22 22" to integer such as 05322222222 .

```
class Phone():
    def __init__(self,input):
        self.phone = input
    def __str__(self):
        return self.phone
    #convert to integer.
    def to_int(self):
        return int((self.phone).replace(" ","").replace("(","").replace(")",""))

test = Phone("0(532) 222 22 22")
print test.to_int()
```

It feels very clumsy to use 3 replace methods to solve this. I am curious if there is a better solution?

Comment: Why?  A phone number is not an integer - it is a string of digits and sometimes other characters.  Converting it to an int serves no useful purpose, and will lose information such as leading zeros.  Don't do it.

Comment: Cutting off leading zeros doesn't matter if the phone number length always stays the same.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
p = "0(532) 222 22 22"
print ''.join([x for x in p if x.isdigit()])
```

Note that you'll "lose" the leading zero if you want to convert it to int (like you suggested in the title). If you want to do that, just wrap the above in a `int()` call. A telephone number does make more sense as a string though (in my opinion).

Comment: Feel free to ditch the square brackets.

Comment: The square brackets are only optional in newer versions of Python.

Comment: @gabe If by "newer" you mean "2.4 or higher", which is 5 years old by now?

Comment: I work on plenty of systems that are stuck on 2.3, and I doubt I'm the only one.

Answer (score 6):

In Python 2.6 or 2.7,
`(self.phone).translate(None,' ()')`
 will remove any spaces or `(` or `)` from the phone string.  See [Python 2.6 doc on str.translate](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) for details.

In Python 3.x, str.translate() takes a mapping (rather than two strings as shown above). The corresponding snippet therefore is something like the following, using str.maketrans() to produce the mapping.
`'(self.phone).translate(str.maketrans('','', '()-/ '))`
See [Python 3.1 doc on str.translate](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) for details.

Comment: great aswell, sucks debian uses 2.5 for stable :(

Comment: @Hellnar: I'm often limited to 2.4 on CentOS 5.  I actually kind of like ChristopheD's answer better than mine anyway.

Answer (score 1):

How about just using regular expressions?

Example:

```
>>> import re
>>> num = '0(532) 222 22 22'
>>> re.sub('[\D]', '', num) # Match all non-digits ([\D]), replace them with empty string, where found in the `num` variable.
'05322222222'
```

The suggestion made by ChristopheD will work just fine, but is not as efficient.

The following is a test program to demonstrate this using the dis module (See Doug Hellman's PyMOTW on the module [here](http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/dis/index.html) for more detailed info).

```
TEST_PHONE_NUM = '0(532) 222 22 22'

def replace_method():
    print (TEST_PHONE_NUM).replace(" ","").replace("(","").replace(")","")

def list_comp_is_digit_method():
    print ''.join([x for x in TEST_PHONE_NUM if x.isdigit()])

def translate_method():
    print (TEST_PHONE_NUM).translate(None,' ()')

import re
def regex_method():
    print re.sub('[\D]', '', TEST_PHONE_NUM)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from dis import dis

    print 'replace_method:'
    dis(replace_method)
    print
    print

    print 'list_comp_is_digit_method:'
    dis(list_comp_is_digit_method)

    print
    print

    print 'translate_method:'
    dis(translate_method)

    print
    print
    print "regex_method:"
    dis(phone_digit_strip_regex)
    print
```

Output:

```
replace_method:
  5       0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (TEST_PHONE_NUM)
          3 LOAD_ATTR                1 (replace)
          6 LOAD_CONST               1 (' ')
          9 LOAD_CONST               2 ('')
         12 CALL_FUNCTION            2
         15 LOAD_ATTR                1 (replace)
         18 LOAD_CONST               3 ('(')
         21 LOAD_CONST               2 ('')
         24 CALL_FUNCTION            2
         27 LOAD_ATTR                1 (replace)
         30 LOAD_CONST               4 (')')
         33 LOAD_CONST               2 ('')
         36 CALL_FUNCTION            2
         39 PRINT_ITEM          
         40 PRINT_NEWLINE       
         41 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
         44 RETURN_VALUE   

phone_digit_strip_list_comp:
  3           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('0(532) 222 22 22')
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (phone)

  4           6 LOAD_CONST               2 ('')
              9 LOAD_ATTR                0 (join)
             12 BUILD_LIST               0
             15 DUP_TOP             
             16 STORE_FAST               1 (_[1])
             19 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (test_phone_num)
             22 GET_ITER            
             23 FOR_ITER                30 (to 56)
             26 STORE_FAST               2 (x)
             29 LOAD_FAST                2 (x)
             32 LOAD_ATTR                2 (isdigit)
             35 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             38 JUMP_IF_FALSE           11 (to 52)
             41 POP_TOP             
             42 LOAD_FAST                1 (_[1])
             45 LOAD_FAST                2 (x)
             48 LIST_APPEND         
             49 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           23
             52 POP_TOP             
             53 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           23
             56 DELETE_FAST              1 (_[1])
             59 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             62 PRINT_ITEM          
             63 PRINT_NEWLINE       
             64 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             67 RETURN_VALUE   

translate_method:
  11           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (TEST_PHONE_NUM)
               3 LOAD_ATTR                1 (translate)
               6 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
               9 LOAD_CONST               1 (' ()')
              12 CALL_FUNCTION            2
              15 PRINT_ITEM          
              16 PRINT_NEWLINE       
              17 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              20 RETURN_VALUE      

phone_digit_strip_regex:
  8       0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('0(532) 222 22 22')
          3 STORE_FAST               0 (phone)

  9       6 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (re)
          9 LOAD_ATTR                1 (sub)
         12 LOAD_CONST               2 ('[\\D]')
         15 LOAD_CONST               3 ('')
         18 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (test_phone_num)
         21 CALL_FUNCTION            3
         24 PRINT_ITEM          
         25 PRINT_NEWLINE       
         26 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
         29 RETURN_VALUE
```

The translate method will be the most efficient, though relies on py2.6+.  regex is slightly less efficient, but more compatible (which I see a requirement for you).  The original replace method will add 6 additional instructions per replacement, while all of the others will stay constant.

On a side note, store your phone numbers as strings to deal with leading zeros, and use a phone formatter where needed.  Trust me, it's bitten me before.

Comment: you don't need character class there, also it would slightly more efficient to use `+` quantifier. The question I have is: "Since when output of `dis.dis` demonstrates efficiency?"

Comment: Yes, you're correct. dis.dis will just give insight into what the compiler is doing, not actual speed of execution.   I'll update the tests to use the timeit module.

Nonetheless, would you agree that re is the best way to do this in a cross-version compatible manner?

Answer (score -1):

SilentGhost: `dis.dis` *does* demonstrate underlying conceptual / executional complexity. after all, the OP complained about the original replacement chain being too ‘clumsy’, not too ‘slow’.

i recommend against using regular expressions where not inevitable; they just add conceptual overhead and a speed penalty otherwise. to use `translate()` here is IMHO just the wrong tool, and nowhere as conceptually simple and generic as the original replacement chain.

so you say tamaytoes, and i say tomahtoes: the original solution is quite good in terms of clarity and genericity. it is not clumsy at all. in order to make it a little denser and more parametrized, consider changing it to

```
phone_nr_translations = [ 
    ( ' ', '', ), 
    ( '(', '', ), 
    ( ')', '', ), ]

def sanitize_phone_nr( phone_nr ):
  R = phone_nr
  for probe, replacement in phone_nr_translations:
    R = R.replace( probe, replacement )
  return R
```

in this special application, of course, what you really want to do is just cancelling out any unwanted characters, so you can simplify this:

```
probes = ' ()'

def sanitize_phone_nr( phone_nr ):
  R = phone_nr
  for probe in probes:
    R = R.replace( probe, '' )
  return R
```

coming to think of it, it is not quite clear to me why you want to turn a phone nr into an integer—that is simply the wrong data type. this can be demonstrated by the fact that at least in mobile nets, `+` and `#` and maybe more are valid characters in a dial string (dial, string—see?).

but apart from that, *sanitizing* a user input phone nr to get out a normalized and safe representation is a very, very valid concern—only i feel that your methodology is too specific. why not re-write the sanitizing method to something very generic without becoming more complex? after all, how can you be sure your users never input other deviant characters in that web form field?

so what you want is really not to *dis*-allow specific characters (there are about a hundred thousand defined codepoints in unicode 5.1, so how do catch up with those?), but to *allow* those very characters that are deemed legal in dial strings. and you can do that with a regular expression...

```
from re import compile as _new_regex
illegal_phone_nr_chrs_re = _new_regex( r"[^0-9#+]" )

def sanitize_phone_nr( phone_nr ):
  return illegal_phone_nr_chrs_re.sub( '', phone_nr )
```

...or with a set:

```
legal_phone_nr_chrs = set( '0123456789#+' )

def sanitize_phone_nr( phone_nr ):
    return ''.join( 
        chr for chr in phone_nr 
            if chr in legal_phone_nr_chrs )
```

that last stanza could well be written on a single line. the disadvantage of this solution would be that you iterate over the input characters from within Python, not making use of the potentially speeder C traversal as offered by `str.replace()` or even a regular expression. however, performance would in any case be dependent on the expected usage pattern (i am sure you truncate your phone nrs first thing, right? so those would be many small strings to be processed, not few big ones).

notice a few points here: i strive for clarity, which is why i try to avoid over-using abbreviations. `chr` for `character`, `nr` for `number` and `R` for the return value (more likely to be, ugh, `retval` where used in the standard library) are in my style book. programming is about getting things understood and done, not about programmers writing code that approaches the spatial efficiency of gzip. now look, the last solution does fairly much what the OP managed to get done (and more), in...

```
legal_phone_nr_chrs = set( '0123456789#+' )
def sanitize_phone_nr( phone_nr ): return ''.join( chr for chr in phone_nr if chr in legal_phone_nr_chrs )
```

...two lines of code if need be, whereas the OP’s code...

```
class Phone():
    def __init__  ( self, input ): self.phone = self._sanitize( input )
    def __str__   ( self        ): return self.phone
    def _sanitize ( self, input ): return input.replace( ' ', '' ).replace( '(', '' ).replace( ')', '' )
```

...can hardly be compressed below four lines. see what additional baggage that strictly-OOP solution gives you? i believe it can be left out of the picture most of the time.