# How to get integer values from a string in Python?

Tags: python, string, integer

Suppose I had a string

```
string1 = "498results should get"
```

Now I need to get only integer values from the string like `498`.  Here I don't want to use `list slicing` because the integer values may increase like these examples:

```
string2 = "49867results should get" 
string3 = "497543results should get"
```

So I want to get only integer values out from the string exactly in the same order.  I mean like `498,49867,497543` from `string1,string2,string3` respectively.

Can anyone let me know how to do this in a one or two lines?

Answer (score 154, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> string1 = "498results should get"
>>> int(re.search(r'\d+', string1).group())
498
```

If there are multiple integers in the string:

```
>>> map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', string1))
[498]
```

Comment: this is not exactly correct, yes it will do for string **starting** with a integer, but if the integer is in the middle of the string, it won't do.

Maybe it should be better to use `int(re.search(r'\d+', string1).group())`

Comment: If `string1` is **(020) 3493**, it fails.

Comment: Right it was the wrong code, should ahve used `re.search`

Comment: @Hussain well, the example only showed numbers at the fron though but anyway now it's safe either way

Comment: This will work fine. But, one should check if result of `re.search` is not **None**. Otherwise, it'll throw an **AttributeError** (`'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`) if there is no digit present in the string after accessing `.group()`.

Comment: @gofmtyourself Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission. The error can be handled in `try` `except AttributeError`

Answer (score 63):

An answer taken from [ChristopheD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/81179/christophed) here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2500023/1225603

```
r = "456results string789"
s = ''.join(x for x in r if x.isdigit())
print int(s)
456789
```

Answer (score 29):

Here's your one-liner, without using any regular expressions, which can get expensive at times:

```
>>> ''.join(filter(str.isdigit, "1234GAgade5312djdl0"))
```

returns:

```
'123453120'
```

Answer (score 20):

if you have multiple sets of numbers then this is another option

```
>>> import re
>>> print(re.findall('\d+', 'xyz123abc456def789'))
['123', '456', '789']
```

its no good for floating point number strings though.

Answer (score 10):

Iterator version

```
>>> import re
>>> string1 = "498results should get"
>>> [int(x.group()) for x in re.finditer(r'\d+', string1)]
[498]
```

Answer (score 7):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> int(''.join(itertools.takewhile(lambda s: s.isdigit(), string1)))
```

Comment: This will only work if the number is at the start of the string. Also, why not use `str.isdigit` instead of the lambda?

Comment: This could also be written as `int(''.join(itertools.takewhile(str.isdigit, string1)))`. I would never actually use either method since this is overcomplicating it.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en&fromgroups#!msg/alt.religion.emacs/DR057Srw5-c/Co-2L2BKn7UJ

Comment: I'm planning ahead for the case where the strings are thousands of characters long.

Answer (score 4):

With python 3.6, these two lines return a list (may be empty)

```
>>[int(x) for x in re.findall('\d+', your_string)]
```

Similar to

```
>>list(map(int, re.findall('\d+', your_string))
```

Answer (score 1):

this approach uses list comprehension, just pass the string as argument to the function and it will return a list of integers in that string.

```
def getIntegers(string):
        numbers = [int(x) for x in string.split() if x.isnumeric()]
        return numbers
```

Like this

```
print(getIntegers('this text contains some numbers like 3 5 and 7'))
```

Output

```
[3, 5, 7]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  integerstring=""
  string1 = "498results should get"
  for i in string1:
      if i.isdigit()==True 
      integerstring=integerstring+i
   print(integerstring)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def function(string):  
    final = ''  
    for i in string:  
        try:   
            final += str(int(i))   
        except ValueError:  
            return int(final)  
print(function("4983results should get"))
```

Comment: not sure why you had to do `return int(final)` just returning `return final` also works.

Comment: also can you explain what is making it bring only digits?

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to remove the trailing the letters using `rstrip` and `string.ascii_lowercase` (to get the letters):

```
import string
out = [int(s.replace(' ','').rstrip(string.ascii_lowercase)) for s in strings]
```

Output:

```
[498, 49867, 497543]
```