# extract id from the URL using Python

Tags: python

I've a URL like this
`url = 'https://www.example.com/contents/6641345'`

I want to extract `id` at the last of `url` you can say the `interger` part from the above string

I tried the solution provided https://stackoverflow.com/a/11339230/2391469 but it gives error
you can test that answer as well by removing the starting numeric values and putting some where else in the code, that code will throw an error

can anybody help me to get this `id`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can either split the string

```
>>> url.split('/')[-1]
'6641345'
```

Or use a regex

```
>>> import re
>>> re.findall('\d+', url)
['6641345']
```

Assuming the urls are always of the format that you showed in your example.

Comment: that's not definitely good to mark every question down, as there are so many new learners in the world, and if this continues(downs) account will be suspended.
So please, avoid it...Thanks

Comment: @Mubin Was that directed at me? I did not downvote you.

Comment: you're the nice one who solved my problem, and those who don't know about this, they focus on to down the questions