# remove URL id from URL in pandas column to leave the base url without id

Tags: python, pandas, url

I am trying to remove the ID's from URLs so that they can be counted in reporting. With the ID's included they are counted as unique urls when they are not. i.e. there are 1000's instead of 10's

so I would like to take a URL like this

```
https://www.website.co.uk/page/home-page/id93847562
```

and cut off the ID so it is like this

```
https://www.website.co.uk/page/home-page/
```

the length of URL varies so I cannot cut using a certain amount of characters from the end or start or use a set amount of backslashes.

I am trying to change the URLS in a column in a pandas dataframe.

the closest to an answer here i could find was this: [extract id from the URL using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26848198/extract-id-from-the-url-using-python)

but I haven't been able to translate it to my scenario

here's my code

```
df.loc[df['URL'].str.contains('id'),'URL' = 'URL'[:id]
```

I've tried to write ' if the URL string contains 'id' replace with the URL from start to id.

the error I get is:

```
File "<ipython-input-18-42dc8b2df1ff>", line 3
    df.loc[df['URL'].str.contains('id'),'URL' = 'URL'[:id]
                                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

any ideas what I can do to make it work?

thank you in advance for any help and advice

Comment: I should mention the datatype is 'object'

Comment: So `Id` always come at the end of url?

Comment: yes but can be different lengths

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `str.replace`

```
df['url'] = df['url'].str.replace('\/id.*', '/', regex=True)
```

**Output:**

```
                                         url
0  https://www.website.co.uk/page/home-page/
```

Comment: perfect deadshot thank you. worked first attempt and is in a format I can use to do similar edits.

Comment: which comma are you talking about? this may help [str.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can do `rsplit` with optional parameter `n=1` to limit the number of splits:

```
df['URL'] = df['URL'].str.rsplit('/', n=1).str[0]
```

---

```
0    https://www.website.co.uk/page/home-page
Name: URL, dtype: object
```

Comment: how does it know which forward slash to use when there are many?

Comment: @MizzH That's why we are using `rsplit` instead  of `split` as it splits the string in the Series from the end..

Answer (score 1):

are the IDs always following a forward slash and at the end of the string? The following code works for me (with those assumptions). I also added a restriction that following "id" there has to be 2-10 digits, but you can of course edit that to fit your use case. Good luck! :)

```
import re
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"url": ["https://www.website.co.uk/page/home-page/id93847562"]})
df["url"] = df["url"].map(lambda x: re.sub(r"/id[0-9]{2,10}$", "/", x))
df
```

Comment: df["URL"] = df["URL"].map(lambda x: re.sub(r"/id[0-9]{2,10}$", "/", x)) 

but it gives: 

TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Comment: strange.. it works in my notebook, but I'm new to python, so I'm not sure where our differences might've come from.. Glad the other answers worked (I didn't see them before submitting mine)!

Comment: could be me, I'm new too!