# python how to extract a number from a variable

Tags: python, variables, integer

I was wondering if in python it would be possible to extract certain integers from a variable and save it as a seperate variable for later use.

for example:

```
str1 = "numberone=1,numbertwo=2,numberthree=3"

newnum1 = [find first integer from str1]

newnum2 = [find second integer from str1]

answer = newnum1 * newnum2

print(answer)
```

Comment: what is your input look like???

Comment: Yes, you can certainly parse the string to extract what you want.

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11339210/how-to-get-integer-values-from-a-string-in-python, try something, if you fail, show what you have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`findall`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

```
num1, num2, num3 = re.findall(r'\d+', 'numberone=1,'
                                      'numbertwo=2,'
                                      'numberthree=3')
```

Now `num1` contains the *string* 1, `num2` contains 2, `num3` contains 3.

If you want only two numbers (thanks to @dawg), you can simply use the slice operator:

```
num1, num2=re.findall(r'\d+', the_str)[0:2]
```

Comment: Since he is only looking for two numbers, you might consider: `num1, num2=re.findall(r'\d+', the_str)[0:2]`

Answer (score 1):

You have some choice for this :

using `str.split()` :

```
>>> [int(i.split('=')[1]) for i in str1.split(',')]
[1, 2, 3]
```

using regular expressions :

```
>>> map(int,re.findall(r'\d',str1))
[1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<==)\d+(?=,|$)
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/yR3mM3/19

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'(?<==)\d+(?=,|$)', re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE)
test_str = u"numberone=1,numbertwo=2,numberthree=3"

re.findall(p, test_str)
```