# How to get the value from a variable for the below scenario ? [Python]

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
my_str = 'I am want you'
    l = ['my_str']
    for value in l:
        print value
```

I would like to fetch the value stored in `my_str`.

Expected output

`I am want you`

Comment: I don't think that's a good idea, instead of you I would use a dictionary.

Comment: `eval(l[0])` should work. Alternatively, you could use `locals()[l[0]]`. But in practice, you probably shouldn't do any of those.

Comment: Thank You Guys, I am cleared now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `eval`.Otherwise use `dictionary` is good approach

```
my_string = 'I am want you'
l = ['my_string']

for value in l:
    print eval(value)

#output
I am want you
```

Comment: In my case, my_string is the variable name used in the other python file. I just need call it one function call

Answer (score 1):

"eval" seems a better solution, but "exec" is also feasible.

```
>>> my_string = 'hello world'
>>> l = ['my_string']
>>> for each in l:
...     exec 'print ' + each
...     exec 'a = ' + each
...     print 'a = %s' % a
...
hello world
a = hello world
```

I also agree that it is an bad idea to use eval/exec for this purpose. Using dictionary might be a better way.

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100% sure what your intention is. But if you want to get integer values from a string in python there are some solutions.

> ```
> >>> import re
> >>> string1 = "498results should get"
> >>> map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', string1))
> [498]
> ```

[Solution from jamylak](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11339230/4760822)

This groups all numbers with the help of a regular expression and then maps them, thus inserting them into an array.

You then just could iterate over this array

```
>>> arr = map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', string1)) 
>>> for num in arr:
>>>     print num
498
```

Edit: Yeah, seems like I misunderstood your question