# NIFI JSON event extraction only integers from string

Tags: jython, apache-nifi

I have a JSON data coming as `{"x":"avc123.abc.com"}`
I would like to have a processor in nifi to extract only the integer (123) from the entire value and output it from the process

secondly, I would like that integer value (123) to be added in the JSON event with different keys such as the final JSON event would be

```
{"x":"avc123.abc.com"
"y":"123"
}
```

I already tried `RouteText` and `ExtractText` processors but it didn't work.

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/q/11339210/2308683 But what if there are multiple numbers like `a1v2c123`? Or multiple keys in the JSON? Is x always the key?

Comment: You may be able to achive this using 'EvaluateJson'(to extract value of x)  + UpdateAttribute (to retrieve integer value) + AttributeToJson ( convert extracted attributes back to flowfile)

Answer (score 0):

I usually don't work with Json data, but I think this might solve your problem, although there might be a simpler way to do it.

```
import json

inpt  = '{"x":"avc123.abc.com"}' # json input.
def ExtractDigits(inpt):
        newstring =''
        dataList = json.loads(inpt) # convert into a python dictionary
        for string in dataList.values(): # loop thru its value
                for x in string:
                        if x.isnumeric():
                                newstring += str(x)
        return newstring

print(ExtractDigits(inpt))
```

You can then add this *'y':'123'* to the ***inpt dictionary*** and then use json.dumps() to reconvert the data into json.
Hope this helps you.