# How can I extract certain characters from a string, convert them to corresponding numeric form and use for calculation in pandas dataframe in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, string, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe `df` as shown (Note: `df.to_dict()` and `df2.to_dict()` is given at the end of the question):

```
Characters  Sum
L1  b3+b1   
L2  b5+b1+b2+b6+b9  
L3  b1+b2+b3+b6+b7+b9   
L4  b1+b5+b12
```

The characters b1, b2, b3 and so on have numeric values embedded with them from another dataframe `df2`.

```
 Buses  Values
    0   bus_1   2
    1   bus_2   3
    2   bus_3   3
    3   bus_4   1
    4   bus_5   6
    5   bus_6   4
    6   bus_7   3
    7   bus_8   7
    8   bus_9   2
    9   bus_10  4
    10  bus_11  6
    11  bus_12  7
```

For example,

```
b1 = df2["Values"][0]
b2 = df2["Values"][1]
b3 = df2["Values"][2]
b4 = df2["Values"][3]
b5 = df2["Values"][4]
b6 = df2["Values"][5]
b7 = df2["Values"][6]
b8 = df2["Values"][7]
b9 = df2["Values"][8]
b10 = df2["Values"][9]
b11 = df2["Values"][10]
b12 = df2["Values"][11]
```

In dataframe `df`, in column `Sum`, I'd like to have the real sum of the values of the characters which are given in `Characters` column. For example, for index L1, I'd like to have value 5 which is corresponding to b3+b1 which is specified in the `Characters` column.

I can split the characters from the string using `split()` method. For example,
`df["Characters"][0].split("+")` gives me `['b3', 'b1']`

But how can I get the numeric values of b3 and b1 and get their sum in another column in `df`? Is it possible to get the sum using any other approaches like `map()`?

`df.to_dict()` is as shown:
{

```
'Characters': {'L1': 'b3+b1',
  'L2': 'b5+b1+b2+b6+b9',
  'L3': 'b1+b2+b3+b6+b7+b9',
  'L4': 'b1+b5+b12'},
 'Sum': {'L1': '', 'L2': '', 'L3': '', 'L4': ''}}
```

`df2.to_dict()` is as shown:

```
{'Buses': {0: 'bus_1',
  1: 'bus_2',
  2: 'bus_3',
  3: 'bus_4',
  4: 'bus_5',
  5: 'bus_6',
  6: 'bus_7',
  7: 'bus_8',
  8: 'bus_9',
  9: 'bus_10',
  10: 'bus_11',
  11: 'bus_12'},
 'Demand (MW)': {0: 2,
  1: 3,
  2: 3,
  3: 1,
  4: 6,
  5: 4,
  6: 3,
  7: 7,
  8: 2,
  9: 4,
  10: 6,
  11: 7}}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get integer values from a string in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11339210/how-to-get-integer-values-from-a-string-in-python)

Comment: I solved the question using eval() as suggested by Eric Lee. It's a different but useful method than the one in the link you shared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One questionable solution would be to just

```
eval('b1+b2+b3+b6+b7+b9'.replace("b",""))
```

I would probably use regex here, but that might be overkill

```
import re
sum(int(i) for i in re.findall('\d+', 'b1+b2+b3+b6+b7+b9'))
```

Comment: Thank you. eval() did the job for me.

Comment: @hbstha123 eval is not a recommended practice, better use `ast.literal_eval`

Comment: Also, I don't see how this answers the question, here it just sums the numbers in the variable **name**, not the matches in `df2`: `b1+b3` would be `1+3`, not `2+3` as it seems it should be from the question

Comment: i used the for-loop statement to get the sum in `Sum` column based on `Characters`.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you want to map the matching Values of Buses of df2 in the sums of df.

An approach would be to `split` the string on `+`, `explode` the column, then `map` each `bx` to the corresponding values of df2 (for this we need to rework a bit df2 to be a Series with the `bx` names as indexes. Finally, `groupby` "Character" and `sum`:

```
(df.assign(Sum=df['Sum'].str.split('+'))
   .explode('Sum')
   .assign(Sum=lambda d: d['Sum'].map(df2.assign(Buses=df2['Buses'].str.replace('us_', ''))
                                         .set_index('Buses')['Values']))
   .groupby('Characters', as_index=False).sum()
)
```

output:

```
  Characters  Sum
0         L1    5
1         L2   17
2         L3   17
3         L4   15
```